# libqmi_cci_intermediates error while building ROM from source

Tags: android, shared-libraries, static-libraries, rom, android.mk

I'm trying to build Turbo ROM ([github source](https://github.com/TurboROM)) for Nexus 4 (device tree [here](https://github.com/TurboROM-Devices/android_device_lge_mako)). I've all required device repos like kernel and vendor. This ROM is AOSP based.

I'm getting following error:

> make: *** No rule to make target
>   '/home/android/TurboROM/out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libqmi_cci_intermediates/export_includes',
>   needed by
>   '/home/android/TurboROM/out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libloc_api_v02_intermediates/import_includes'.
>   Stop.

Can anyone help me? I'm fairly experienced in building ROMs from source but not able to get past this error.

Comment: Can you share your Android.mk file

Comment: Added tags , need to verify Android.mk , need to check if it is linking statically or using shared libs

Comment: What Android.mk would you like to see?

Comment: Share above more logs related to build failure . Make sure you have setup android build environment including all libs.  The above error will be thrown when it fails to build particular target , say for example some application TelephoneServices, etc

Comment: I built the ROM by commenting out this line https://github.com/TurboROM-Devices/android_device_lge_mako/blob/mm/device.mk#L204'code'

and it was successful. Initially I thought, GPS would not work, but to my surprise, it was working.